# What p from `preg_match` stands for?

Tags: php

In ruby, there is a function called `gsub`, where g stands for `global` and sub stands for `substitution`.

What `p` from `preg_match`?

I suppose `reg` is for `regular` and `match` is really `match`. Is that correct?

Comment: @micro.widmer, true, closing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does stand for "Perl REGular expression".

Comment: @fotanus it relates to the syntax coming from Perl's regular expressions. To distinguish it from the old PHP regular expressions which used a different syntax.

Comment: Here's the catch: it's not even *supposed* to stand for Perl regex, it's supposed to stand for PCRE, which is not the same as native Perl regex. I never understood why they prefixed the functions with `preg_` instead of `pcre_`.

Comment: @BoltClock please answer with this info, then I can select your answer before closing this. It is a too valuable information to be in comments

Answer (score 1):

its perl, as [preg](http://www.pcre.org/) is an implementation of the perl regular expression engine

Answer (score 1):

It stands for [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/).

Answer (score 0):

P stands for Perl in 'preg'.

They comes under  Function list.[PCRE : Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)